# What is the difference between Nearby sharing and Bluetooth sharing on Android?

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer, images, data-connection, bluetooth-pairing

Both can be used to share files, so how they are different?

Comment: As far as I know "Nearby sharing" can make use of Wifi and thus transfer larger files in a shorter time. And as you require Android 6 on both devices it may make sense to also show the old simple Bluetooth sharing.